# Why friend function needs a declaration outside of the class

Tags: c++

for the following code:

```
class A {
    friend void fun(){};
};

int main() {
    fun();
}
```

I know that it is illegal since `fun` cannot be find with normal lookup rules. My question is: why C++ choose this design and doesn't let `fun` to be find?

Thanks!

Comment: @sweenish - It's not private. It's not visible to name lookup at all. A private function would still be found (albeit with a slap on the wrist for trying to touch it).

Comment: Good points. I hastily commented, as I know I've implemented friend functions in a class declaration before, but there was obviously something different going on with my implementations versus this one.

Comment: That's what's called a **hidden friend**, and it can be hard to get to if it does not have the class as a parameter, which allows for ADL.

Comment: This is the difference my implementations had.